# Optimal way to save a keras model to save space

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, h5py

I have trained a model in keras with the help of transfer learning on the top of the vgg16 model as mentioned in the blog [Building powerful image classification using model using very little data](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html).

When I saved the model using `model.save()` method in keras the ouput file size(in **.h5**) format was about 200MB.

I need to push this code in github but we can't upload a file whose size is more than 100MB.

So, is there any way so that I can save the model in a file of lesser size.

**Note** :: I need the model only for prediction purpose

Comment: Maybe using h5py with apropriate compression filters or this https://gist.github.com/lukedeo/d1899f011ae41b26fb6e would help?

Answer (score 4):

The [docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) have your solution. `save` is optimal, but is there to easily save and load the  entire state for continuous work. You need much less if I understand correctly:

> Saving/loading only a model's architecture

```
json_string = model.to_json()
yaml_string = model.to_yaml()
```

> Saving/loading only a model's weights

```
model.save_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
```

Both I guess are much leaner then the entire working area. You can use these to recreate the model later on, as stated in the docs (`load_weights`, `load_from_json`, etc.).

Comment: I cannot recreate the model, later on, only the work left is prediction. So is **model.to_json** better than **model.save**

Comment: @AkashChandra I'm not sure what you mean, but `model = model_from_json(json_string)` will re-create the model so you can use it. It's all in the docs.

Comment: My bad, sorry on my part. I will rephrase my question which function should be used **model.to_json** or **model.save** i.e. which format is better **.h5** or **.json** in terms of space.

Comment: `json`, for sure - That was your question and what I answered, no need to double check. Using the above you're saving much less than with `save`, so you need a lot less space.

Comment: But if you want to use that trained model for prediction, you will need to save the weights as well. And in my experience, the weights are the more data-heavy part of a model.

Comment: @KiraMichiru I think it's still significantly less than a plain save.

Comment: please follow the [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/), it gives an optimal way to save the model i.e. first saving the model in JSON format and then storing its weight.

Comment: @kabanus, my bad I missed the link.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to save such a model using significantly less space.

However, if your problem is not the file size itself but the **upload file size limit**, you can try to **split the file** into several chunks that are smaller than that limit and upload those, e.g. using [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/). See [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36947/how-to-upload-really-large-files-to-skydrive-dropbox-or-email/) link for a tutorial on how to split the file.

Comment: Thank you, my problem was **upload file size limit** in GitHub as GitHub doesn't allow files greater than 100MB size to be uploaded. So I reduce the size by saving the model in the format mentioned in this [site](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/).

Comment: you don't want to have your models on git. try tools like dvc if you want to version them